# Abstract Method using Implementation level method

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, abstract-base-class

I'm implementing some classes for adjusting prices in my Ecommerce site: each class represents a different pricing adjustment strategy and belongs to an AbstractBaseClass which stipulates two methods:
`transform_price` and `transform_array`.

```
class PricingModel(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def transform_price(self, price):
        ...

    def transform_price_array(self, price_array):
        return [self.transform_price(price) for price in price_array]
```

Since `transform_array` is simply a list comprehension of the `transform_price` method (which is, of course, implementation specific) I was hoping there would be some way to fully abstract this method in a way such that it still executes the *implementation-specific* method `transform_price`.

For example I would like to be able to define a PricingModel:

```
class PriceRatio(PricingModel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
    
    def transform_price(self, price):
        ...
        return new_price
        
    # Note the abscence of a transform_price_array method!
```

While still being able to access the transform_price_array method defined in the abstract class:

```
_ = PriceRatio.transform_price_array([1,2,3,..])
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this behaviour is enabled by default.

Removed all of my implementations of the `transform_price_array` method, leaving only the abstract method and all my tests still passed!

[image]

Comment: Yes, because you never declared `transform_price_array` to be an abstract method. It's not that you can't *call* an abstract method, it's that you can't *instantiate* a class that hasn't overriden all inherited abstract methods.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My thinking was based on the incorrect view of ABCs as a sort of parent class, a paradigm within which it doesn't make sense for instances to access methods of a parent class which in turn access methods of the specific instance. I have now come to understand ABCs as being more like a 'template' class, in which case the above description makes perfect sense.